# rollmeanr issue with NA

Tags: r, zoo, moving-average

for a base, let:

```
library(zoo)
x1=c(1,2,3,4)
x2=rollmeanr(x1,2,fill=NA)
x=cbind(x1,x2)
     x1  x2
[1,]  1  NA
[2,]  2 1.5
[3,]  3 2.5
[4,]  4 3.5
```

But if there is a `NA` in the base, `rollmeanr` does not work anymore:

```
x1[1]=NA
x3=rollmeanr(x1,2,fill=NA)
cbind(x1,x2,x3)
     x1  x2 x3
[1,] NA  NA NA
[2,]  2 1.5 NA
[3,]  3 2.5 NA
[4,]  4 3.5 NA
```

`x3[3]` should be `2.5` cause it has the 2 precedent data.
Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: I can't reproduce your results. For me x3 works just fine.

Comment: xm1, consider upgrading your version of `zoo`. According to `zoo`'s [NEWS](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/NEWS), at version 1.8-2 the behavior of `rollmean` changed in the presence of `NA`.

Comment: tks, @r2evans -  it was zoo version - R version is 3.5.0 - tks, phiver.

Comment: @r2evans wanna answer so I can upvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zoo` changed the behavior of `rollmean` around version 1.8-2 (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/NEWS):

> Changes in Version 1.8-2
>
> - The rollmean(x, k, ...) method now calls rollapply(x, k, (mean), ...) in
>     case x contains any NAs (as the fast cumsum-based solution in rollmean is
>     not applicable in this case). Analogously for rollsum() and rollmedian().
>     (Reported by Jan Gorecki.)

So the behavior you're seeing is in version 1.7; if you upgrade to 1.8 (as I'm guessing @phiver has done) then you should see your expected results.